# After using a redirect in my routes, font awsome and ionicons are no longer loaded

Tags: laravel, cors, font-awesome, adminlte, ionicons

I am using Admin LTE on top of laravel, I have installed both font-awesome and ionicons using npm and included them using laravel mix, both these packages have successfully been added to my app.css file but when I utilise a redirect from my routes (i.e redirect to dashboard from successful login) it seems as though the neither font-awesome or ionicons are being sourced from the app.css file anymore and i am returned this error -

> Redirect from
>   '/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512'
>   to
>   'https://c9users.io/_user_content/authorize?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fp%2Ffonts%2Fvendor%2Fbootstrap-sass%2Fbootstrap%2Fglyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf%3Fe18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://'
>   is therefore not allowed access.

I do not want to allow access control and specifically used laravel mix to avoid this

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to answer from source. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)